# Cancel notification in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

i have a reminder application, it triggers notification for few of the tasks, suppose if i delete or opens a notified task i want to clear that particular notification

i tried this solution

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Here, always while opening the task i need to call this method with notification ID, so does it cause problem to my application?

If so, is there a way to check if the notification for a ID is exist & then clear it?

Comment: there will be no problem if you try to cancel a notification with an id that does not exist

Comment: I read in one post saying, above code leads to phone restart sometime? is there any alternative way to cancel notification?

Comment: I have never heard of such a problem

Answer (score 1):

You can clear notification by setting notificationId (used while generating the notification)
Or alternatively set it as autoCancel so that when user performs the notified task , it will disappear automatically from the notification tray. You can do the same by :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        NotificationManager notif = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "tittle", System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
        notify.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "subject",
                "body", pending);
        notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notif.notify(0, notify);
```